# Altium: Deleting the "room" object in the PCB view

Tags: altium

When I carried out "Import changes from ..." into my PCB view, the components from the only schematic were all imported into it. However, it also created a box that has same name as the schematic file itself. Please see this image below:

[image]

I am not completely sure why this has been created. Is it safe to delete this? I believe that a room is used to group components that must all be placed within it. I could be wrong since I have never used it so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's completely safe to delete the room. You can also set some preferences to keep them from being created in the first place.

Comment: Specifically: Project Options / Classes / Generate Rooms.

Comment: Have you ever had to use "rooms"?

Comment: Oh, yes. They are quite handy with multi-channel designs and can save a lot of work.